# Can I deploy code to the Developer environment from repository via SFDX if code doesn't have enough test coverage?

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, deployment, sandbox, developer

I tried using:

> sfdx force:source:deploy -u user@gmail.com -c -p force-app/main/default -l RunSpecifiedTests -r Class1Test

But it still runs all unit tests

How could I deploy the code to the Sandbox without running any unit tests or only the unit specified above?
Is there SFDX command that enable to validate / deploy code without unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandboxes and Developer Edition orgs require no coverage or unit tests at all, and you can further add extra flags to try and force the deploy to be accepted.

Try:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -f -g -o -l NoTestRun -u username -p force-app/main/default
```

This overrides conflict warnings, disables warnings and errors, and skips all unit tests. If this fails for any reason, you either have a compilation error, or you're trying to deploy to production instead of a Sandbox, Developer Edition, or Scratch Org.

Make sure you check the login you're using. You can use:

```
sfdx force:org:open -u username
```

To verify which org you're connected to.

Comment: Thanks! That first command solved the issue